# HTML5 - how do i add a container?

Tags: html, css

Im new to web development so just need some help with this.

I created boxes behind my heading 1 and heading 2 and i do not know how to center align them? I am not familiar with div. as of yet.

html

```
<h1>Pitbull Publo's Photogallery </h1>

<h2>A photo gallery of the worlds CUTEST Pitbull, from Puppy to Beast.</h2>
```

These are in between the style tags:

```
        h1 {
            color: #992343;
            width: 700px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: #F7EF84;
            border: 1px ridge #df80ff;
            position: center;
            text-align: center;
            }

        h2 {
            color: #992343;
            width: 700px;
            height: 75px;
            background-color: #F7EF84;
            border: 1px ridge #df80ff;
            text-align: center;
            }
```

I need to create a Container for the boxes. please help!

Comment: Where's the code for the boxes you created?

Comment: it seems like you have used heading tag instead of div. use a common div and enclose your headings in it.

Comment: add `display: block; margin: 0 auto;` to each h tag

Answer (score 1):

Try using margin: 0 auto; to center your headings

```
 h1 {
        color: #992343;
        width: 700px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #F7EF84;
        border: 1px ridge #df80ff;
        position: center;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        }

    h2 {
        color: #992343;
        width: 700px;
        height: 75px;
        background-color: #F7EF84;
        border: 1px ridge #df80ff;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        }
```